# html, width 100% and padding

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with margins. I want to have image inside div element. Height should be of the image, but width should be of the parent div minus padding.

```
 <div class="inner">
      <img width="100%" src="http://pawelek-moj-aniolek.blog.onet.pl/wp-content/blogs.dir/505303/files/blog_bg_734362_1406866_tr_morze.jpg" alt="There is no image"/>
 </div>
```

and styles

```
  .inner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
   }

 .inner img {
       width: 100%;
  }
```

and the problem is easy to see on the image.

http://i59.tinypic.com/zn6mc2.png
I want to have 10 pixels of white place around each side of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use another div to wrap the image and give:

```
padding:10px;
```

insteed of margin.

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f6jju2mn/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:100%` from the `inner` class. Update your CSS like below.

```
  .inner {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
   }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w1zwbaxf/)

Comment: it works fine on the right side, but on the top is still wrong. Image http://i60.tinypic.com/spdp4n.png

Comment: did you check my demo link? It is working fine here. May be it will overwrite with some other styles.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width:100%;` for `inner` class

```
.inner {

        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
   }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmc51su2/)